# cleaning a string in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, data-cleaning, python-re

i have the following column :

[image]

i want to remove the link and and any unnecessary symbols
i've tried this :

```
def clean(col) : 
col =  re.sub("http\S*\s", "", col)
return col
PalEng["Content"] = PalEng["Content"].apply(str)
PalEng["Content"] = PalEng["Content"].apply(clean)
```

it worked for some rows , but the majority didn't change

Comment: Can you provide some detail behind what you reference as unnecessary symbols?

Comment: i want to keep '? ! , . @' and remove the rest
in addition to that '\n' i think it mean that they jumped the line

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of "https://"

```py
yoursting.removeprefix("https://")
```